# Are there any Puranas that corresponds to a Kalpa where Brahma creates Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, puranas, brahma, kalpa

According to the thirteenth chapter of the Vayavivasamhita of the Shiva Purana, Brahma has created Vishnu and Rudra in certain Kalpas:

> Vayu said, I shall narrate how Rudra was born and how Brahma and Vishnu were born from each other.
>   The three are Atmans as causes of born of Mahesvara; they are cause of creation, sustenance and annihilation of the Universe consisting of mobile and immobile beings. Endowed with great qualities they are sanctified by great Lord. Presided over by his Shakti, they can perform their activities. Brahma can create, Vishnu can protect and Rudra can annihilate.
>   But they rivaled with one other. Desirous of excelling one other they propitiated their father the Supreme Lord by means of penance. Attaining all around favor of Lord at outset in Previous Kalpa, Rudra created Brahma and Vishnu. **In another Kalpa, Brahma created Vishnu** and Rudra. In another Kalpa, Vishnu created Brahma and Rudra. Thus in different Kalpas, Brahma, Vishnu and Rudra desiring mutual benefit are born of one another. Based on the events in their respective Kalpas, their process in being the cause of origin of one other is extolled by Sages. (**Chapter 13, Vayavivasamhita, Shiva Purana**)

Now, I have only seen Puranic references of Brahma having created Rudra but I have never encountered a single occasion so far where Brahma created Vishnu. Rather, it is generally Vishnu who creates Brahma.

Since each Purana corresponds to different Kalpas, I want to know whether or not any Purana corresponds to a Kalpa where Brahma created Vishnu?

Comment: As far as one can tell, all Brahma is not created at the end of every kalpa. Rather, after Brahma completes one lifetime, prakritika pralaya happens and it is after this pralaya that Brahma, Rudra and other devatas are created. During His lifetime, Brahma oversees creation of several kalpas. However, in the beginning of the present kalpa, Vishnu APPEARED from Brahma's nostrils as Shweta Varaha to uplift Bhu Devi from patala. Appearing from Brahma and getting created by Brahma are different things.

Comment: I'm just going to blame Tamasic Purana uncertainty on which incarnation it's talking about for this confusion.

Comment: My goodness, according to Padma puran, puranas are classified into sattvik, tamasik and rajasik.Again this very Padma puran says that all Puranas are the body parts of Lord Vishnu and are a mode of moksha and as lord vishnu is sattvik in nature all Puranas should be sattvik.Plus According to skanda puran vaishnav purans are tamasik and Shaiva purans are sattvik respectively.Now, according to Mahabharata all 18 purans are same n gives moksha.So all these are sectatarian bs so I m gonna blame them for ts confusion and brainwashing murkh people and also these stupid ppl who believes in it.Period.

Comment: So Padma puran contradicts itself only.So these are nothing but interpolation by some kaliyugi ppl.For Shaivas Vaishnav purans are tamasik and for Vaishnavas Shaiva Purans are tamasik.But for a true devotee all Puranas are equal.Otherwise Vedavyasa has a 1st class vip ticket booked for hell as no 1 can write something without reading it or reciting it.So choose ur own tamasik puran for yourself like a fool, but I am gonna go with mahabharata an epic Itihasa only. Bde, It's talking about the original one only no incarnation as said in my ans below. Prd. Hara Hara Mahadeva, Jai Mata Di, Hari Om.

Answer (score 7):

it's given in the next few lines only of Chapter 13, Vayavivasamhita, Shiva Purana, When Brahma Created Vishnu. They are as follows.:

> Now listen to their holy and wonderful story that releases from sins.
>
> 22-26. Listen also to what happened to Brahmā in his Kalpa. **In the Kalpa, Meghavāhana,** Viṣṇu became a cloud and showered the earth for a thousand divine years. Seeing this, Śiva gave imperishable Śakti to Viṣṇu. Obtaining the Śakti from Śiva Viṣṇu created the universe along with Brahmā. On seeing that glory of Viṣṇu, Brahmā created by him was seized by jealousy and said derisively. Go you, O Viṣṇu. The cause of your origin is known to me. Rudra is superior to both of us. There is no doubt in this.
>
> 27. It is due to the grace of that lord that you, the sustained have become a creator today.
> 28. I too shall propitiate Rudra, the leader of gods, by means of penance and shall create the entire universe along with you. There is no doubt in this.
> 29. Slighting Viṣṇu thus, Brahmā attained Śiva by means of penance and submitted to him thus.
> 30. O lord of the gods, O lord of the universe, Viṣṇu is born of your left and I am born of your right side.
> 31. Still Viṣṇu created the universe along with me. Due to rivalry he was taunted by me depending on the strength of your support.
> 32. “O Viṣṇu, your piety towards the lord is not more than that of mine” (I told him) because our origin from you is on the same footing.
> 33. O Śiva, it behoves you to give all that to me also in the manner you bestowed on him before due to his devotion.
> 34. Thus implored by him the merciful lord Śiva gave all to him as justifiable.
> 35. Thus obtaining the state of being the Atman of all in a trice, from Śiva, Brahmā hastened to and saw Viṣṇu.
>
> 36-41. He saw Viṣṇu lying on Śeṣa[1] in his abode in the milk-ocean.[2] A white canopy resembling the sun was spread. It was created by him mentally. It was set with gold and gems. Lord Viṣṇu had eyes resembling lotus. He had splendid body with four arms. He was bedecked in ornaments. He was holding conch and discus. His face shone like the disc of the moon. The scar Śrīvatsa marked his chest. He was smiling sweetly. His lotus-like feet attained red hue due to the contact of the lotus-like Lakṣmī. In Yogic slumber he appeared lying in the nectarine milky ocean. By the Guṇa of Tamas he was Kālarudra; by that of Rajas he was Brahmā; by that of Sattva he was Viṣṇu. In Nirguṇa state he was lord Śiva. **On seeing him Brahmā spoke seriously—“O Viṣṇu, I am going to devour you as you did me formerly.”**
>
> 42. On hearing this Viṣṇu woke up, saw Brahmā and smiled slightly.
> 43. **In the meantime Viṣṇu was devoured by Brahmā and immediately created through the middle of the eyebrows.**
>
> 44-47. In the meantime the moon-crested lord came to the place to test their Śakti. Though devoid of form he assumed a form in order to bless them as he had previously done. Both of them were delighted and frightened and so eulogised the lord and bowed to him with respect from a distance. The trident-bearing lord blessed them and vanished even as they watched him with respect.

So in the kalpa of meghavahana Brahma and Vishnu simultaneously created each other respectably. There may be other kalpas also where brahma created vishnu. As the verses of your question states clearly but this is only circumstance I found as of now where Brahma Swallowed Vishnu and created him again from the middle of his eyebrows as his son. So due to the boon given them by Mahadeva, the tridevs create each other in different different kalpas respectably. Period.

Comment: That's a Nice find!